# Send and collection of data from one server to another

Tags: javascript, php, post

**UPDATE**

Objective post data (age and name) from `www.domain1.com` to `www.domain2.com/try.php`

**Problem**
am getting this on `domain2.com/try.php`

> Undefined index: name
>
> Undefined index: age

**Index.html on domain1**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#clickMe").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: 'www.domain2.com/try.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        name: "tom",
                        age: "30"
                    },
                    complete:
                            function (data) {
                                window.location = "www.domain2.com/try.php";
                            }
                })

            })
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme123"/>
</body>
</html>
```

**try.php on domain2**

```
    <?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];

echo 'name:'.$name;
echo 'age:'.$age;
```

Comment: `server to server` means passing the value into `one domain to another domain`?

Comment: @prasad yes domain to domain

Comment: @Progrock server two is just a plain page that will output through a echo the variables received

Comment: @Progrock you are correct, perfect. I was posting to get.php but ill update my question to make it easier to read

Comment: Why don't you just post from one domain to the other using a html form?

Comment: sorry was at lunch, ill try this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first domain just use a form and post to the second domain:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://two.example.com/foo.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="tom">
            <input type="hidden" name="age" value="30">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works, but i was trying to use JavaScript so i can use dynamic variables from one domain to another and so its more secure. +1 for simple answer though